# List changes in a file using git show

Tags: git

**git show SHA#1** will gives all the changes of commit **SHA#1**. I am just curious that is there a way for list changes of a specific file ( filter out result of **git show SHA#1** for get changes of a file) of SHA#1 using **git show**.

I know that I can do it using **git diff**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add your filename :

```
git show <sha1> <filename>
```

For more details on how to specify the object you want to show, see [`girevisions`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html).